# how are we able to use emit() and delay() functions without any instance in Kotlin Coroutine?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

```
fun simple(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    println("Flow started")
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100)
        emit(i)
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("Calling simple 
   functionn...")
    val flow = simple()
    println("Calling collect...")
    flow.collect { value -> 
   println(value) } 
    println("Calling collect 
   again...")
    flow.collect { value -> 
    println(value) } 
}
```

To call a function in a class we use Object of the class with . Operator but in Kotlin Coroutine how are we able to use emit() and delay() functions without using any object (as shown in the above code) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different things here.

### The `emit()` inside a flow case

There's a receiver defined for that scope. In Kotlin a function type (like `(Int) -> Int`) can also take a "receiver", like this: `SomeObject.(Int) -> Int`. That means that when that lambda is called a SomeObject instance will be passed and will act as an implicit "this" that will "take" invocations by default. You can read more about that here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types

### The `delay()` case

Ths is much simpler. Kotlin suopports global functions. Functions that are not really associated with a class (internally the Kotlin compiler will create a class and put those functions there as static methods). You can Ctrl-Click on `delay` and see how is defined.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear! Remember to accept the answer if you think it helped! =)

Comment: @Nikhilkumar Again, remember to accept the answer if it helped. =)